# Svelte - bind on child component's property

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an app that simply hides content `Hidden.svelte`:

```
<script>
    export let shown = false;
</script>

<svelte:options accessors={true}/>

{#if shown}
    <slot/>
{/if}
```

Everything works fine in parent `App.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import Hidden from 'Hidden';

    let child;
</script>

<Hidden bind:this={child}>
    Content
</Hidden>

<button on:click={() => child.shown = true}>Show</button>
```

---

But, although I can do this `on:click={child.shown = true}`, I can not do this:

```
{#if child.shown}
    External message!
{/if}
```

Obviously, I also can not do this:

```
<div class:shown={child.shown}>Child component is shown</div>
```

---

I guess, thats all because it renders before mounting, but all my attempts playing with `onMount` and `$:` failed

Could it be achieved somehow? Thx

**EDIT**

Sorry, everyone, I've tried to make as simple example as possible, and made one that does not reflect my initial problem at all, but, however, technically got the right answer

So, the problem was, that parent `App.svelte` did not reflect `child.shown` changes that was made directly inside `Hidden.svelte`

@ThomasHennes suggested to use stores to solve that, but, if I got it right, it is good approach for single app instances, so, for those who are interested, I ended up with regular events:

https://svelte.dev/repl/f467fe36446444f09a2a7633b1faa6a1?version=3.20.1

**EDIT 2**

Real problem solved in accepted answer

Comment: Can you create a REPL? I am a bit flabbergasted by the child variable which is null at first, but then suddenly an object. https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.20.1

Comment: @Gh05d https://svelte.dev/repl/c8667fd89c8442259233b0d3aa4b996b?version=3.20.1
Ye, I've previously missed `export`, now its fine

Comment: So, the problem is solved?

Comment: @Gh05d Sorry, things gone far, so, I've added "EDIT" block, and, for now, question closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may have overlooked a more direct possibility: [bind:property](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property).

While `bind:this` is very useful to grab DOM elements, I tend to consider it a last resort solution with components.

If you manage to make Svelte aware of what needs to be tracked, chances are that the resulting code will be more performant than if you roll your own with events or whatever. In part because it will use Svelte's runtime code that is already present in your app, in part because Svelte produces seriously optimized change tracking code, that would be hard to hand code all while keeping it human friendly. And in part because your change tracking targets will be more narrow.

Also, you'll get more concise code. More boilerplate left handling by the machine means more available human for the actual logic.

So... If you're interested in the changing value of a prop, you can bind to the prop. Here's how I would do it.

`Hidden.svelte`

```html
<script>
  export let shown = false // <= you can bind to this!

  export const show = () => { shown = !shown } // <= you can bind to this, too!
</script>

<button on:click={show}>Child's button</button>

{#if shown}
  <slot/>
{/if}
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import Hidden from './Hidden.svelte'

  let shown
  let show
</script>

<button on:click={show}>Parent's button</button>

<Hidden bind:shown bind:show>
  <div>Hidden content</div>
</Hidden>

{#if shown}
  <div>Hidden child is shown!</div>
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/538575b696464db4911a6f032c8c3798?version=3.20.1)

Comment: Can you elaborate why `bind:this` is a "last resort solution" for components?

Comment: There is a dimension of personal preference to it. I don't like to expose more than strictly necessary to external consumers, because it makes it harder to track usages. If you find a `bind:prop` in a consumer, you know `prop` is used (which you already kind of knew since the prop is part of the "public" API of the component). Done. If you find a `bind:this`, you now need to track all usages of this `this`. If, god forbid, the instance is further exposed globally... You're fried. JS is very permissive, so IDEs can't help a lot with usage tracking / refactor, and so I like my code very closed.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to test `child` along with `child.shown`:

```js
{#if child && child.shown}
    External message!
{/if}

<div class:shown={!child || !child.shown}>Child component is shown</div>
```

See https://svelte.dev/repl/10f1e41e4fc3465d81bba5efcff84c4a?version=3.20.1

You could also use a reactive value to manage the combined conditions:

```js
$: childShown = child && child.shown
```

and subsequently use `childShown` or `!childShown` to conditionnally display content.

Comment: Big thx for help, but you helped me to figure out that I've just created an oversimplified example that did not reflect real problem. If `shown` is changed somehow in child's component - problem still exists https://svelte.dev/repl/f6f3d82466194719ba5dfe9dadd36e65?version=3.20.1
But, I am a little bit confused about what to do now, mark your answer as correct and create new question, or create and EDIT block to this post?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, it seems very wrong to me that you define `shown` as a prop (`export let shown = false`) then proceed to modify its value from within the child component. To do what you appear to be aiming to do, I would instead use a store, which would give access to the tracked state to any component that subscribes to it (in your case, parent and child).
As for the answer resolution, I leave it up to you to decide if the original question has been answered or not.